# URL truncated when it contains semicolons

Tags: java

I'm running a Java Spring application on Tomcat that accepts HTTP requests from a web browser. My URL requests are of the form http://some_server/search/id/123;456

The javascript library function encodeURIComponent is used to encode any special characters from the URL before sending it to the application
e.g. http://some_server/search/id/123%3B456

However, remote debugging the application reveals that the URL request is truncated at the semicolon. I.e. the URL only contains characters before the semicolon like so: http://some_server/search/id/123

Debugging beakpoint was at the entry point in the controller where Spring MVC provides the HttpServletRequest.

Many thanks for any assistance provided.

Comment: A `%` is not a "semicolon". Anyway, you'll need to post some code to get a chance of a proper answer, preferably a [mcve].

Comment: @daniu `%3B` is, which is what's in the url

Answer (score 0):

You should use pattern in `@RequestMapping` like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/id/{id:^[0-9;]+$}")
public String test(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) {}
```